# No Minyan: Tired Netz vs. More Awake Later

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, hanetz-sunrise

Scenario: Minyanim are not available.

Is it preferable to pray at Netz with lower kavana (tired) or later in the morning (before zman krias shema) with more kavana (better rested)?

Although CYLOR, I'm curious if the Poskim discuss this question.

Comment: Preferable to go to sleep earlier...

Comment: Indeed DoubleAA - Rav Wolbe zatzal in Alei Shur says that Shacharis starts with going to bed at the right time the night before.

Comment: https://www.ou.org/holidays/shavuot/hilchos-uminhagei-shavuos/ by shavuot source go down and get to the second number 2 and 3 and there they talk about it

Comment: עי' בנטעי גבריאל פכ"א סי' א', ובפרדס אליעזר פ"ג

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like there is much discussion, but based on the letters from the Lubavitcher Rebbe below (concerning whether to daven or go to sleep after staying up all night) ( אגרות–קודש כ"ק אדמו"ר ח"ג ע' תלד.
ח"ט ע' רלט) it is clear that if going to sleep will add כוונה then it is more important than to daven ותיקין.

There is a known [Rambam](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93) that any davening without כוונה is not considered a davening. Therefore, one who stayed up all night should, in general, go to sleep for a few hours to help his כוונה. (If it doesn't then there is no reason to go to sleep especially if one will feel groggy afterwards.)

Based on The Lubavitcher Rebbe's approach, כוונה is the main focus in davening. Therefore just like these individuals could have davened ותיקין but the Rebbe told them that if it will help their כוונה then go to sleep, so too in your case it seems that you should daven later in the morning.

[image]
[image]